# Cannot Run Qt Installer Application on MAC(Mojave)

Tags: macos, qt, shell, macos-mojave, qt-installer

I have developed a camera application for MAC platform. The app executable and framework dependencies were bundled into an installer app named **QtCameraInstaller** (developed using Qt Framework). This installer app, perform unzip process to extract the compressed files.

```
QTProcess process;
process.start("/bin/sh unzip /User/MyMac/Desktop/test.zip");
```

**Case #1:**
[image]

By clicking the installer application, I was able to run the installer. Exactly the *unzip shell commands(part of my Qt code) were not working*. The unzip task were skipped, resulted in unsuccessful installation of my Camera App (dependencies found missing after the installation).

**Case #2:**
[image]
When I tried to run the installer resides inside the bundled package, I was able to install the application successfully (i.e) now the shell commands were working fine. The unzip commands were working and dependencies were copied successfully.

MAC OS Version: **10.14.5(Mojave)**

Can someone please help to fix the problem in Case #1 ?

What differs between **Case #1** vs **Case #2** ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try modifying it to this:  `/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/unzip /User/MyMac/Desktop/test.zip`

It a suggestion that may work, considering you may not have a full environment on the first case, so passing the exactly path with the -c may help.